# Finding angles of dots to make a mechanical wave effect

Tags: language-agnostic, waveform

This is just only for fun.

I want to know the formula of getting the **angle** of each one of those dots rotating in their corresponding circles.

These are my given values:

- number of rows
- number of columns
- radius of their circle(universal)

And this is the picture I want to achieve:

[image]

I assume that the speed of rotation of each dots are uniform

**Update:**

Yayks! Thanks for all your answers. However, I manage to make my own too but in different pattern:

[image]

By doing the logic only in the constructor side:

```
CircleWithDots() : timer(clock()), angle(angle_counter = (angle_counter >= REVOLUTION - 1) ? 0 : angle_counter + ANGLE_STEP) { }
```

Where:

```
REVOLUTION = 360 + 1;
ANGLE_STEP = 20;
```

And also this one (for rotating dot):

```
x = table_cos[angle] * radius;
y = -table_sin[angle] * radius;
```

Comment: it think the angle itself can be obtained via a combination of 2 `sin` (or `sin` and `cos`) functions, the input to each would be row and colum

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I came up with an idea by just taking a screenshot of it(not moving) that the angles are just `x` greater than the previous angle as the rows and columns increased. Hmm

Comment: i think if you just add `x` you will end up with a zig zag pattern instead of a smooth curve

Comment: try it with a `sin` where the input is only the row (normalized to [0,1] range), I think you will end up with a horizontal wave

Comment: They align diagonally so something like `(xpos-ypos)*scale_factor` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Like I said in my comment it's merely the diagonals lining up,so all you have to do is

```
(xpos-ypos)*scale_factor
```

Here's a processing js sketchpad (it's kind of slow, you can just copy paste it into a local processing installation to see it run faster):

http://sketchpad.cc/yT0pQfbYXV

The relevant part is:

```
        ang = (x-y) * scalefac + anim;
        float xpos = x*xscale+ sin(ang)*cwidth/2.0;
        float ypos = y*yscale+ cos(ang)*cheight/2.0;
        arc(xpos,ypos,4,4,0,PI*2);
```

[image]

if anyone wants a tileable version here it is:

[image]

Comment: Waw! That looks almost the same as the GIF I posted. Nice work :D

Answer (score 2):

What a blast!
This was a fairly simple exercise as it turned out. There were a couple of steps and an important realization.

First, I noticed that in a horizontal row there were 16 circles to each cycle, simialar with the y axis. It seemd reasonable to me to guess that the angle step between horizontal neighbours would be the same as the vertical ones. Therefore, if circle 0,0 was at 0deg, circle 0,1 would be at (360 / (16+1)) deg and so would the circle 1,0.  (*Note:* I used 360/16 in the source)

I simply increment the position of the circle's origin for each column and each row. A also increment the angle offset for each column and row. Using an offset leaves me with the ability to have the position of each dot different to the others in the row/column, while also giving me the ability to step through the animation by increasing it.

Here's a running example:
http://jsfiddle.net/GVTsB/

[image]

The important part of the code is the function to draw each frame. Both circle-drawing functions take the center-point of the circle.

```
function drawFrame(angleOffset)
{
    var can = byId('dest');
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    var x, y, xStep, yStep;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);

    for (yStep=0; yStep<21; yStep++)
    {
        angle = yStep * (360 / 16);
        angle += angleOffset;

        y = yStep * 460/20 + 0.5;
        for (xStep=0; xStep<21; xStep++)
        {
            x = xStep * 460/20 + 0.5;
            drawCircle(x,y, 21, ctx);

            var pos = calcPos(angle, 21);
            pos.x += x;
            pos.y += y;
            fillCircle(pos.x,pos.y,3,ctx,'red');
            angle += (360 / 16);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good. Seems slightly off, though, as well as the dot rotation being backwards from in the question.

Comment: Cheers. Tired eyes I guess. :) It's a simple matter of inverting the y co-ordinate returned from calcPos. I.e increasing y in screen-space heads down, whereas the trig functions have +y heading upwards. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

One possible equation of relative motion of any pair of dots [I, J] is

```
AngularPosition[I, J] = SquareRoot((-X[I] + X[J])^2 + (-Y[J] + Y[J])^2)
```

where

```
VectorPosition[I, J] = (-X[I] + X[J], -Y[J] + Y[J])

-X[I] + X[J] = sin(K*t + PhaseDiffXofDots[I, J])

-Y[I] + Y[J] = cos(K*t + PhaseDiffYofDots[I, J])

{ Or it could be same, sin or cos in both X and Y directions }


PhaseDiffXofDots[I, J] = (-(circle[I]CenterX + (circle[J]CenterX))*H

PhaseDiffYofDots[I, J] = (-(circle[I]CenterY + (circle[J]CenterY))*V
```

where
`X` is horizontal position in array 
`Y` is vertical position in array
`t` is time, 
`K` is constant speed of rotation of dots, 
and `H`, `V` are phase differences between nearby circles, horizontally and vertically ( probably H = V here)